# Getting [Object Object] when i try to send data from Img Tag onclick function (LWC)

Tags: lightning-web-components

```
<template>
    <lightning-layout multiple-rows>
        <template if:true={carsFound}>
        <template for:each={carList} for:item="cari">


             <lightning-layout-item size="6" key={cari.Id} >

                  <div class="slds-box">
                     <div> {cari.Name}</div>

                     <div>
                         <img src={cari.Picture__c}  onclick={triggerevent} id={cari} > 
                     </div>
                    </div>

             </lightning-layout-item>


        </template>
    </template>
      </lightning-layout>
</template>
```

```
import { LightningElement,api,wire } from 'lwc';
import getCars from '@salesforce/apex/getCars.getCars';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import{CurrentPageReference}    from 'lightning/navigation';
import { fireEvent }   from 'c/pubsub';

export default class CarForm extends LightningElement {
    @api getcarslist;
    carList;

   @wire(CurrentPageReference) pageRef;

    triggerevent(event)
     {  //const data1 = event.getAttribute("data-car-type");
         const id1 = event.target.id;
       // console.log('event from trigger' + data1.Name);
       console.log('id'+ id1);  I am getting [object Object] followed by " - any number"
      /* for (let value of Object.values(id1)) {
        console.log('value1'+value); // John, then 30
      }*/


        fireEvent(this.pageRef,
        'carListUpdate',
          id1); 


    }

     @wire(getCars,{ key: '$getcarslist'})
      getcar({data,error})
        { console.log('inside carshow');
            if (data)
             { this.carList = data;

                data.forEach((element)=>
                  { const cars={};
                    cars.Availforrent     = element.Available_For_Rent__c;
                    cars.carId            = element.Id;
                    cars.carName          = element.Name; 
                    this.carList.push(cars);                    

                  });


                console.log('carList'+this.carList); 

             }
          else if (error)
          {  console.log('error in murali new code'+error.body.message);
             this.showToast('ERROR', error.body.message, 'error');

          }

         }
         showToast(title, message, variant) {
             const evt = new ShowToastEvent({
                 title: title,
                 message: message,
                 variant: variant,
             });
             this.dispatchEvent(evt);
         }

         get carsFound(){
             if(this.carList){
                 return true;
             }
             return false;
         }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cari` refers to an entire object. Thus, you're getting an object. Instead, pass in the Id:

```
<img src={cari.Picture__c}  onclick={triggerevent} data-id={cari.Id} />
```

Note that `id` is reserved by the framework, so you should use a data attribute instead (demonstrated above).

You should change your script accordingly to get the value:

```
const id1 = event.target.dataset.id;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot..it did work for me!!

Answer (score 0):

The id you are trying to use it not the id of your object, but the object itself.
Instead of

```
<img src={cari.Picture__c}  onclick={triggerevent} id={cari} >
```

you need to use the id, not the object:

```
<img src={cari.Picture__c}  onclick={triggerevent} id={cari.Id} >
```

Just like you reference the name further up with `<div> {cari.Name}</div>`